# How to view google docs or a word files in a flex application?

Tags: flash, apache-flex, ms-word, google-docs, document-conversion

I am evaluating flex for a mobile and a web application and one of things I want to be able to do is show a google docs or a microsoft docs file (doc,ppt) within a flex application.

Google docs files are published as web pages so I guess you need a html component with javascript enabled. Does such a component exist in flex 4+?

Similarly how would I go about showing a word or a powerpoint file inside a flex app? How does a site like slideshare or scribd do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To view office style files in a Flash based application you should look up a tool similar to Flash Paper.  (Note: Flash Paper no longer exists as a product' it was killed sometime after Adobe bought Macromedia ).

I think the gist is that a conversion happens--probably on the server--which turns the document into a Flash format.

[Print2Flash](http://www.print2flash.com/) is one product.

[FlexPaper](http://www.devaldi.com/?p=212) is another tool for displaying PDFs.

I would not expect that Google Docs would be viewable in a Flex application at all.  Scribd uses a tool that reminds me of FlashPaper.  I thought Slideshare had created something custom to convert powerpoints into Flash accessible.  I had assumed it converted PPT to PNG (or JPG) which it them displays in a custom built Flash app.

Comment: As a possible solution, you *could* use have Flex call a javascript function that create an overlay with the google docs.  That would be compatible since google docs is all javascript.  Another solution would be to just get the data from google docs and display it however you choose.  Last solution is if you're using Air, you can use the html component to show the google doc directly.

Comment: i like the AIR approach better. Thanks!